# Error using GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server

I get the following error :

**Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'TempRH.utilisateur_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**

When executing the following query :

```
    SELECT MAX(TempRH.poids)as poids,TempRH.utilisateur_id  
    FROM TempRH 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT TempRH.utilisateur_id 
                FROM TempRH 
                GROUP BY TempRH.utilisateur_id
                HAVING COUNT(*)>2) t
    ON t.utilisateur_id =TempRH.utilisateur_id
```

Please help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TRY THIS**

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
    SELECT MAX(TempRH.poids)as poids,TempRH.utilisateur_id  
    FROM TempRH 
         INNER JOIN 
              (SELECT TempRH.utilisateur_id
               FROM TempRH 
               GROUP BY TempRH.utilisateur_id 
               HAVING COUNT(*)>2)t
         ON t.utilisateur_id =TempRH.utilisateur_id
    GROUP BY TempRH.utilisateur_id  
)x
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using an [`Aggregate`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) function, you need to `GROUP BY` any other columns from your `SELECT` statement.  Adding

`GROUP BY TempRH.utilisateur_id`

to the end of your query will resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are selecting `utilisateur_id` together with the `Max(poids)`, you will need a group by on the outer level as well.

One point - if you are joining back to the same table from what looks like to be a key, it should be possible to simplify your query as follows:

```
SELECT MAX(TempRH.poids)as poids, TempRH.utilisateur_id  
    FROM TempRH 
    GROUP BY TempRH.utilisateur_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```